# Making a default style for a menu item separator in WPF, within the scope of a particular menu

Tags: wpf, contextmenu, menuitem, separator

I'm trying to change the way a separator appears in my WPF context-menu. The context menu has its own default style, which is already successfully applying a style to all of its menu items.

```
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource ContextMenuBaseStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type local:ViewportContextMenu}">
    <!-- Defining this style in Style.Resources means ALL menu items within the Context Menu, no matter how nested, use this style by default. -->
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource MenuItemBaseStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <!-- Set the icon of all menu items to the one associated with their data context -->
            <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{StaticResource ViewportMenuItemIcon}"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">
            <!-- Make the separators big and red so I know this style is working. -->
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="100"/>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

By defining the MenuItem style as keyless, and within the resources of my ContextMenu style, it seemed I was able to create a 'default style' for MenuItems within the scope of my ContextMenu control.

I figured I could do the same with Separators, yet this style doesn't seem to be getting applied (as is the case with WPF, it's extremely difficult to figure out what style is actually active on a given control)

Comment: A Margin of 100 (100, 100, 100, 100) is likely pushing the Separator out of the ContextMenu (to the right by 100). Even if your Style had been applied properly, I wouldn't expect to see the Separator.

Comment: I can see the separator and it looks normal.

Answer (score 0):

When you just set the `Style.TargetType` your implicit `Style` will only target `Separator` controls outside the `Menu` (or `ContextMenu`). This is because the `Menu` loads the `Style` explicitly by a key.
This key is defined as [`MenuItem.SeparatorStyleKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.menuitem.separatorstylekey?view=windowsdesktop-8.0#remarks) static property.
This means you must override the `Style` that uses this key explicitly, so that when the `Menu` looks up the resource with this key finds your custom `Style`:

```xml
<Style x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.SeparatorStyleKey}" 
       TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">

  <!-- Make the separators big and red so I know this style is working. -->
  <Setter Property="Background"
          Value="Red" />
  <Setter Property="Margin"
          Value="10" />
</Style>
```

Be aware that you may run into the same issues when styling submenu items. They use explicit keys too.
You can check Microsoft Docs: [Menu and MenuItem ControlTemplate Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/menu-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#menu-and-menuitem-controltemplate-example) to learn about the used keys.

Comment: If this is true then why is my style for menu items being correctly applied?

Comment: If what is true? The MenuItem style keys are optional in case you want to style toplevel and sublevel items differently. But SeparatorStyleKey is looked up explicitly.